# Convert the result of dynamic sql to xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I want to execute the following T-sql

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = 'select 1 a, 2 b for xml path (''''), root(''root'')'
declare @t table (x xml)
insert into @t exec (@sql)
```

However, I got the error message of

> Msg 6819, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
>
> The FOR XML clause is not allowed in a INSERT statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embed the query that creates the XML in one extra select statement.

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = '
select
  (
  select 1 a,
         2 b
  for xml path (''''), root(''root'')
  )'

declare @t table (x xml)
insert into @t exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example where you insert another column (like a primary key) as well as the xml column?